# can not create file in Android

Tags: java, android, xamarin, ioexception

I have developed an Android application using Xamarin. I try to save file to external storage but it fails. Of course my application has `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` and `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` but I can not create a new file. 
For instance I have the following code:

```
var fl = new Java.IO.File(Path);
if (!fl.Exists())
    if(fl.CanWrite()) // this is false
        fl.CreateNewFile();
```

And if I call `fl.CreateNewFile()` I get `fl.CreateNewFile()` with message `fl.CreateNewFile()`. As I wrote previously all necessary permissions are granted (I checked it in runtime too). In addition I noticed that this does not happen with every device. 
What could it be the reason? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you trying to write to a SD storage? Please note that Google disabled the possibility to write to SD storages since Android 6

Comment: @DarioAckermann it is Android 4.4 and yes I write to SD storage

Comment: Messed something up. This is disabled since KitKat  Version (4.4.2), not since Android 6. Sorry!

Comment: What is the "path" that you are trying to write to?

Comment: @SushiHangover path is "/mnt/sdcard/syncThree/tmp.mp3"

Comment: Alway use `Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory` to get the base "external" directory. "/mnt" should never be used directly as permissions on that dir are totally different.

Comment: @SushiHangover I changed Path as you advice but it has no effect. I again get `open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)`

Comment: What was the path you ended up constructing?

Comment: @SushiHangover I'm sorry but English is not my native language and I didn't understand your last phrase

Comment: What is "x" in `var x = System.IO.Path.Combine(Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.Path, "syncThree", "tmp.mp3";`

Comment: @SushiHangover x is "/storage/sdcard/syncThree/tmp.mp3"

Comment: If you use `adb` to check exists/permissions. Does `adb shell ls -l /storage/sdcard/syncThree` report `sdcard_rw` permissions? If `tmp.mp3` already exists, what permissions does that file have? `adb shell ls -l /storage/sdcard/syncThree/tmp.mp3` Is it `sdcard_rw`? If not, delete it and start again